# 2001 Pontiac Grand Am stalls while driving!

Tags: pontiac, stall, grand-am

My 2001 Pontiac stalls out while driving we’ve replaced loads of stuff with no luck. It begins losing power and the more gas you try to give it the more it wants to die. It sat for 2 years prior and I’ve only had it for a couple months but the whole time I’ve had it the problem has only gotten worse. At first it only did when I went long distances but now it won’t even make it a mile without losing power and dying. Replaced the following:1 oxygen sensor (the one under the hood),fuel filter,brake lines,coils,map sensor,spark plugs &wires,cut catalytic converter off and none of this helped at all. The battery is also hooked up using jumper cables can this cause issues? If anyone has any ideas please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!